# how to add link button using datatable as datasource to gridview dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable, linkbutton

Here i did every thing from codebehind.I created a gridview dynamically.

DataTable dt=null;
 dt = loadDynamicGrid(columnname, ds);

GridView grdnew = new GridView();

grdnew.DataSource = dt;

grdnew.DataBind();

```
private DataTable loadDynamicGrid(string [] column,DataSet ds)
{       
    #region Code for preparing the DataTable

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    //Create an ID column for adding to the Datatable
    DataColumn dcol ;//= new DataColumn(ID1, typeof(System.Int32));
    ButtonColumn btncolm;
    HyperLinkColumn hplink;

    for (int i = 0; i < column.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (column[i] != "" & column[i]!=null)
        {
            if (column[i] == "BUY" || column[i] == "Buy" || column[i] == "BuyNow" || column[i] == "Details" || column[i] == "ViewDetails" || column[i] == "BuyQty" || column[i] == "Purchase")
            {
                //btncolm = new ButtonColumn();
                //btncolm.HeaderText = column[i];
                //btncolm.Text = column[i];

                //dt.Columns.Add(btncolm.Text);
                hplink = new HyperLinkColumn();

                hplink.HeaderImageUrl = "http://www.google.com";
                hplink.HeaderText = column[i];
                hplink.Text = column[i];
                dt.Columns.Add(hplink.Text);

            }
            else
            {
                dcol = new DataColumn(column[i], typeof(System.String));
                dt.Columns.Add(dcol);
            }
        }
    }

    int k=0;

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        DataRow myrow = dt.NewRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < column.Count(); j++)
        {
            if (column[j] != "" & column[j] != null)
            {

                string sdfsd = Convert.ToString(dr[column[j]]);
                if (column[j] == "BUY" || column[j] == "Buy" || column[j] == "BuyNow" || column[j] == "Details" || column[j] == "ViewDetails" || column[j] == "BuyQty" || column[j] == "Purchase")
                {
                   //myrow[column[j]] = "http://www.google.com1/";
                   myrow[column[j]] = dr[column[j]];
                }                    
                else
                {
                    if (Convert.ToString(dr[column[j]]).TrimEnd() == "&nbsp;")
                    {
                        myrow[column[j]] = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myrow[column[j]] = dr[column[j]];
                    }
                }
                if (column[j] == "Stock" || column[j] == "QtyInStock" || column[j] == "Qty" || column[j] == "Available" || column[j].ToLower() == "onhand" || column[j] == "QuantityOnHand" || column[j] == "QtyAvailable" || column[j] == "InStock" || column[j] == "Avail" || column[j] == "Inventory" || column[j] == "Quantity" || column[j] == "Availability")
                {
                    if (Convert.ToString(dr[column[j]]) != "0" && Convert.ToString(dr[column[j]]) != "" && dr[column[j]] != null && Convert.ToString(dr[column[j]]).TrimEnd()!="&nbsp;")
                    {
                        stock = dr[column[j]].ToString();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        k++;
        dt.Rows.Add(myrow);          

    }       

    #endregion

    column = null;

    return dt;      
}
```

Then i adding to a div everytime like:

mydiv.Controls.Add(grdnew);

as above i repeate the loop for different table of data to bind to gridview.Here i need a link button to gridview.so i added a hyperlink column to datatable,but i'm not getting any linkbutton in grid.I have more than 20 tables of data to bind to grid.so i preferred to create the grid dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace the grid with datagrid and add hyperlinkcolumn to datatable and give data to that column as click me

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();

HyperLinkColumn hplink = new HyperLinkColumn();
hplink.Text = column1[i];
dt.Columns.Add(hplink.Text);

DataRow myrow = dt.NewRow();
myrow[column1[l]] = String.Format("<a href='" + imageUrl(gettablename(tablename)) + "' target='_blank'>" + dr[column[j]] + "</a>");

 dt.Rows.Add(myrow);
 DataGrid1.DataSource=dt;
 DataGrid1.DataBind();
```

Thats it problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
    TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
tc1.Wrap=true;
this.lnkRecvGpNo=new LinkButton();
lnkRecvGpNo.Text="RecvGp No";
this.lnkRecvGpNo.Click+=new EventHandler(lnkRecvGpNo_Click);
tc1.Controls.Add(lnkRecvGpNo);
```

Comment: ,do i need to change from grid to table?

Comment: why?? this is for your table if you want to generate the linkbutton in table and if you wish to dynamically add link in grid view create a templatefield & generate linkbutton in that.

Comment: if you are creating new template field for grid put that code in databound of gridview and if using above do where you add columns to table

Comment: as i shown my above code,i didn't create any template field for the grid i'm directly assigning the datatable to the grid datasource,so how to add a linkbutton?

Comment: I'm created a Hyperlinkcolumn to datatable while i find the column header with name "But" or "ViewDetails" and adding the hyperlinkvolumn instead of the datacolumn,but this hyperlinkcolumn not added as a linkbutton or linkcolumn to the gridview,so how achieve link column in gridview while addding datatable as datasource?